# Assigning keyboard shortcut to Powerpoint VBA macro programmatically

Tags: vba, powerpoint, keyboard-shortcuts

Need to define Keyboard shortcut via code itself 
or is there any other method to give have standard keyboard shortcut apart from quick access ribbon button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this PowerPoint add-in help you? Disclaimer : I am not affiliated with the publisher, just offering a link to a product I am aware of.

http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html

Comment: Yeah i too check this add-in. But my requirement: Is  there any VBA code to define key board shortcut. I have created a set of add-in to serve my process, but what i'm missing is a simple keyboard cut for them.

Comment: Did you miss the link at the bottom of the page that Jamie pointed you to? http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr_sdk.html

Comment: Steve's right to point that SDK link out as there is no mechanism in [PowerPoint] VBA to assign macros to keyboard shortcuts. It's just not Excel!

Comment: Thank you soo much folks :)